# One-sided Conversations in Adium

Tags: adium

When using Adium, sometimes someone will initiate a conversation with me, and while I can see the stuff they write to me, they don't see my responses.

Closing the conversation window and starting a new conversation solves the problem.

I think, but am not sure, that this happens only when the other side is using Windows Messenger.  (In other words, I don't think I ever see it for Yahoo! or AIM chats.)

Anybody else seeing this?  Any advice for fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

I'v never heard of or seen that error before.  You're best off posting a bug ticket here: http://trac.adium.im/.